# Read bash script arguments multiple times

Tags: bash, shell, optional-parameters

I have a bash script which can be passed a number of different arguments and variables to be used by the script itself. Some of the parameters get assigned to variables. The **second while loop** does not appear to be running when the program tries to execute it. I've simplified the following script for confidentiality/simplicity reasons.

```
./myscript --dir2 /new/path
while :; do
  case $1 in
    --var1) $var1=$2
    ;;
    --var2) $var2=$2
    ;;
    "") break
  esac
  shift
done

$dir1=/default/directory
$dir2=/default/directory

while :; do
  case $1 in
    --dir1) $dir1=$2
    ;;
    --dir2) $dir2=$2
    ;;
    "") break 
  esac
  shift
done

echo "Expect /default/directory, returned: $dir1" 
echo "Expect /new/path, returned: $dir2"
```

Here's what my program would effectively return.

```
Expected /default/directory, returned: /default/directory
Expected /new/path, returned: /default/directory
```

Is there a better way to go about this? Or another way to iterate over the parameters originally passed to the script? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You've shifted all the arguments out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve your arguments, you can copy them into an array, and then restore the original list from that array later:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ - must be invoked as bash, not sh, for array support

# Copy arguments into an array
original_args=( "$@" )

# ...consume them during parsing...
while :; do # ...parse your arguments here...
  shift
done

# ...restore from the array...
set -- "${original_args[@]}"

# ...and now you can parse them again.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your using `shift` which consumes the elements. Try using a for loop to iterate over the args. There's a few ways to do this. Here is my preferred method:

```
for elem in "$@" # "$@" has the elements in an array 
do
   ... # can access the current element as $elem
done
```

Another way is to access them by index, you can look up a tutorial on bash array syntax for that.

Comment: Needs to be `in "$@"`, not `in $@` -- without the quotes, you get identical behavior to unquoted `$*` (effectively concatenating all your arguments into a single string, then splitting that string into words and expanding each word as a glob).

Comment: BTW, `for elem do` will also have this effect -- `"$@"` is the default thing for a `for` loop to iterate over.

Comment: Follow up question to this answer, what would the syntax be for accessing $elem+1?

Comment: @JensPetersen, one can't -- that's a significant downside of this answer. You could iterate by indexes, though -- `for ((idx=1; idx<=$#; ++idx)); do elem=${!idx}; next_idx=$((idx + 1)); if (( next_idx <= $# )); then next=${!next_idx}; else next=; fi; printf 'elem=%q next=%q\n' "$elem" "$next"; done`

Comment: Great to know! Looks like I'm going with the original_args solution. :)